# Как заменить некоторое число символов зная их номера?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть строка вида

```
11010010101101
```

и ключ, массив, например:

```
array(
'3' => '1', 
'5' => '1', 
'10' => '1'
);
```

строка хранится в базе, ключ передается в *$_SESSION*

Задумка такова, что получив строку из базы, позиция 3, 5, 10 заменяются с 0 на 1 (отсчет позиций начинается с 1). Т.е. на выходе должна получиться строка вида:

11**1**1**1**0101**1**1101

пробовал через ***str_split()*** загнать строку из бд в массив посимвольно, но не могу додумать как полученными двумя массивами (строки и ключей) обращаться, чтоб добиться желаемого результата.

Данный массив-ключ приведен для примера, сам по себе он динамический и может иметь от 1 до количества символов в изменяемой строке (в данном случае 14) ячеек.

**UPD: [РЕШЕНИЕ]**
по решению ниже, сделал в виде функции

```
function genNew($word, $key_array=array())
{
    $split_word = str_split($word);
    foreach ($key_array as $key => $array_elements)
    {
        $split_word[$key-1] = $array_elements;
    }

    $new_word = implode($split_word);

    return $new_word;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$word = '11010010101101';
$keyArray = array(
    '3' => '1',
    '5' => '1',
    '10' => '1'
);
$splitWord = str_split($word);
foreach ($keyArray as $key => $arrayElements){
    $splitWord[$key-1] = $arrayElements;
}
$newWord = implode($splitWord);
```

В `$newWord` будет новая строка с измененными символами.

Comment: А зачем split и implode если php и так позволяет работать с строкой как с массивом. Т.е. `$word[3-1]` тот же 3й байт в строке и его точно так же можно заменять

Answer (score 1):

Битовую строку до 32 символов можно хранить как integer.
Для ключа длиной 14 символов операция `$n |= 1<<13-2` устанавливает 3-й по счёту бит

Вывести ключ в строку можно командой `sprintf("%14d", $n, $str)`.

Answer (score 0):

Не слишком ли это накладно - байт на байт менять через разбиение на массив??? Плюс, как насчет проверки - есть ли вообще байт в позиции, на которой его хочется заменить?

Данный фрагмент кода заменяет байты прямо в строке. Хочется сохранить исходную строку, используйте копию в другой переменной. Всего кода - 3 значащих строки.

```
$s="11010010101101";
$repl = array(
  '3' => '1', 
  '5' => '1', 
  '10' => '1'
);

echo $s."\n";
$l = strlen($s);
foreach($repl as $num=>$char) {
  if ($num>0 && $num <$l) $s[$num-1]=$char;
}
echo $s."\n";
```